# Understanding the summation symbol

Tags: real-analysis, summation, notation

In our script, we have following use of the summation symbol:

$(*) \sum_{i=1}^2(a_i+c)$, c is some constant.

I know that this is supposed to summarize $a_1+a_2+c$, however the way it is written with the summation symbol in (*) it seems to be $a_1+c+a_2+c$. What is correct?

Comment: It's $a_1 + c + a_2 + c = a_1 + a_2 + 2c$. It's _not_ $a_1 + a_2 + c$, since the $c$ is summed _twice_. If you want the $c$ to be summed once, then you should leave out the brackets.

Comment: I thought so, but then the rest of the equations do not make sense. Thank you for the quick answer...!

Comment: PS: The symbol should be $\sum_{i=1}^2\ldots$

Comment: I know I thought it was clear..

Comment: @Pegah - then you were mistaken. The rest of us only know that $i$ starts at 1 because of your later interpretation.

Comment: Interesting, I often see this notation. But I have edited it now

Comment: According to your "supposed" answer, I guess the original should have been $( \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i)+c$